# How to fix an Undefined array key error in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
        $luckyNumbers = array (4,5,6,1,2,34);
        
        for($i=0; $i <= count($luckyNumbers); $i++){
            echo "$luckyNumbers[$i] <br>";
        }                 
?>
```

I was trying to output

```
4
5
6
1
2
34
```

But the warning below is appearing - I just use the asterisk to cover folder name.

> Warning: Undefined array key 6 in C:\Users******\php project\index.php on line 315

So the output becomes like this.

```
4
5
6
1
2
34

Warning: Undefined array key 6 in C:\Users\******\php project\index.php on line 315
```

Why is the error appearing when the output is right?

Comment: This is the code I used:  <?php 
        $luckyNumbers = array (4,5,6,1,2,34);
        
        for($i=0; $i <= count($luckyNumbers); $i++){
            echo "$luckyNumbers[$i] <br>";
        } 
        
        
        ?>

Comment: Because your array has six elements whose indexes start at 0. 5 is therefore the last index. Looping number 6 is the problem because it doesn't exist - as the message is telling you, index 6 is not defined

Comment: Use `print_r($luckyNumbers);` to see the structure and indexes. Use `i < count($luckyNumbers);` to fix the bug (note `<` instead of `<=`)

Comment: ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach instead

```
<?php 
        $luckyNumbers = array (4,5,6,1,2,34);
        
        foreach ($luckyNumbers as $luckyNumber){
            echo "$luckyNumber <br>";
        }                 
?>
```

Comment: This will work, but your answer would be improved if you had explained why the OP's solution had failed, and why your solution will work.